# because search filter with mybatis and spring returns the entire table

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

I am doing a search engine with spring and mybatis so I have to filter by two records in my table, so in the oracle documentation I got the NVL function but I can't successfully implement it to my query

```
SELECT 
    FC.COD_FCD,
    FC.DSC_FCD, 
    DS.DSC_DSL ,
    FC.COD_EST_GNC, 
    FC.COD_HBT 
FROM SPFS_DT_FACUL FC 
INNER JOIN  SPFS_DT_DSPLG DS 
    ON FC.COD_DSL = DS.COD_DSL 
WHERE 
    (
        FC.COD_AB='01' 
        AND FC.COD_FCD LIKE #{value1}||'%'
    ) 
    OR (
        FC.COD_AB='01' 
        AND FC.DSC_FCD LIKE #{value2}||'%'
    )
```

I wait for the filtering of the records but the whole table returns to me

Comment: I don't see `NVL()` in your query code.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. Which one is your question? What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle, any non-null value matches on condition `LIKE NULL || '%'`.

I think that you are trying to avoid the conditions to match when one (or both) parameter is `null`. The simplest way would be to explictly check for nullness:

```
SELECT 
    FC.COD_FCD,
    FC.DSC_FCD, 
    DS.DSC_DSL ,
    FC.COD_EST_GNC, 
    FC.COD_HBT 
FROM SPFS_DT_FACUL FC 
INNER JOIN  SPFS_DT_DSPLG DS 
    ON FC.COD_DSL = DS.COD_DSL 
WHERE 
    FC.COD_AB='01' 
    AND 
        ( #{value1} IS NOT NULL AND FC.COD_FCD LIKE #{value1}||'%' )
        OR ( #{value2} IS NOT NULL AND FC.COD_FCD LIKE #{value2}||'%' )
    )
```

Also please note that I factorized your conditions `(A and B) or (A and C)` to `A and (`B`or`C`). This makes the expression shorter and easier to understand.